# Editing fields in Javadoc IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I am rather new to java and for one of my assignments am looking into how to add information for the methods in each of my classes. I am using the IntelliJ Idea Editor.

Comment: What is your question exactly? To add javadoc, well, you write it, as documented: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using the **JavaDoc**.

```
import java.io.*;

/**
* <h1>Add Two Numbers!</h1>
* The AddNum program implements an application that
* simply adds two given integer numbers and Prints
* the output on the screen.
* <p>
* <b>Note:</b> Giving proper comments in your program makes it more
* user friendly and it is assumed as a high quality code.
*
* @author  Zara Ali
* @version 1.0
* @since   2014-03-31
*/
public class AddNum {
   /**
   * This method is used to add two integers. This is
   * a the simplest form of a class method, just to
   * show the usage of various javadoc Tags.
   * @param numA This is the first paramter to addNum method
   * @param numB  This is the second parameter to addNum method
   * @return int This returns sum of numA and numB.
   */
   public int addNum(int numA, int numB) {
      return numA + numB;
   }

   /**
   * This is the main method which makes use of addNum method.
   * @param args Unused.
   * @return Nothing.
   * @exception IOException On input error.
   * @see IOException
   */
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {

      AddNum obj = new AddNum();
      int sum = obj.addNum(10, 20);

      System.out.println("Sum of 10 and 20 is :" + sum);
   }
}
```

After adding all the information for Documentation in **Intellij IDEA** go to **Tools -> Generate JavaDoc...** then specify the **Output directory** and click **OK**
Here is more detailed information on how to use **Generate JavaDoc Dialog** in **IDEA** - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-javadoc-dialog.html
Also take a look at the Oracle's Style Guide **How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool** - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Good luck!